# Cannot run on self hosted runner of github actions bundle install with docker-compose run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I was using the self hosted runner of github actions to build the CI environment.

We use docker for development, and docker-compose is used to manage the configuration of the development environment.

The CI also uses a set of commands using docker-compose on Github Action, and it worked without any problems.

However, one day I suddenly lost the ability to run any process using the docker-compose run command.

```
Creating redis ... 
Creating db    ... 
Creating es01       ... 
Creating redis ... done
Creating es01       ... done
Creating db    ... done

Creating api_run ... 
Creating api_run ... done
# This should be followed by bundle install, but it's not.
```

We have confirmed that it works fine for local and non-self hosted actions.

We have also confirmed that docker-compose run using ssm on the target EC2 instance works correctly.

I'm not sure why this problem is happening, but if you know anything about it, or if there is something wrong with this, I'd like to hear about it.

Here is part of the CI configuration

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    name: Running Test
    runs-on: self-hosted
    timeout-minutes: 20
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: docker-compose build
        run: |
          docker-compose build

      - name: bundle install
        run: |
          docker-compose run --rm api bundle install
...
```

Thank you for your time.